# Plank to behave like Mac OS dock

Tags: plank

Is there a way to make the plank behave like the Mac OS dock. What i mean by this is that when the active window is not maximized or not in full-screen mode, then the dock should act as if the hide dock behavior is disabled, But if the active window is maximized or in full-screen mode then the hide dock behavior activates. I don't want to use the Auto-hide or InteliHide behavior because this causes some apps to open and overlap the dock which its in a normal state (Not maximized).

Comment: Hide when: Focused window is maximized. Isn't that what you want? You have it in settings.

Comment: We do, but what that enables is that when you open a window, it can overlap the dock. I don't like it when a window is opened behind the dock, i then have to drag it above the dock myself.

Comment: Try Window Dodge setting. That's what I use and it works like it does on Mac

Comment: In case you are wondering where Window Dodge is: Ctrl+Right click on the dock > Preferences > Behaviour > Window Dodge. Default is set to 'Dodge maximized window'. Let us know if this is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how macOS's dock behaves, but it sounds like the behavior you're describing is:

1. By default, the dock is shown
2. When no apps are maximized/fullscreened, windows don't ever automatically cover the dock (technically, the dock would not hide and would set struts, behaving like the hide mode is just turned off)
3. When a window is maximized, hide the dock

To me this sounds like a relatively small (and probably good) modification to the existing "dodge maximized window" behavior, and is probably best suited for a bug filed against Plank: https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank